# Maven dependency management and IDEs: `import` scope

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have a few multi-module maven projects. It's Java EE application, so all of them go to single EAR file eventually, and that's why there is a special separate POM, where all the dependency management is described for 3-rd party dependencies:

```
<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>my-3rd-party-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

It also imports JBoss AS parent POM in it's dependency management section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-parent</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Every project has it's own parent, where I describe

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-3rd-party-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and every sub-module just describe their dependencies without versions.

This works perfectly, when you use command line. All the dependency versions resolved correctly.

But in IDE (I tried IDEA, Eclipse and NetBeans) I get errors.

**IDEA**

```
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 63, column 29 less...
```

**Eclipse**

```
For artifact {org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)
```

while the version for `org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec` is in the JBoss AS parent POM.

Why this happens and how can I resolve this to work in IDE without errors?

Comment: how do you import your projects into IDE? I think, you should provide your sub-modules as modules in parent pom and import into IDE only parent pom.

Comment: That's correct, I import parent POMs in IDE. All sub-modules imported automatically by IDE then.

Comment: I've reproduced this error (on simpler case). I managed to get rid of error by completely removing dependencies without version. Code still could be compiled. Could you try that?

Comment: No, the whole idea as to have versions in one place, and do not duplicate versions in modules. And of course I can't just remove dependencies, because I use classes from them.

Comment: once again: I placed dependency in parent pom and removed it completely from module pom and it works both from cmd and IDE (IDEA) because modules inherit dependencies from parent. If you package your projects as jars it makes no difference at resulting artifact at all. If your goal is to specify versions at one place, you could consider using variables in parent pom and then use them in modules (like <version>${var1}</version>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it finally, the problem was caused by the fact that this `dependencyManagement` section was inside profile in the `my-3rd-party-deps` POM. My bad that I didn't mentioned it in the question.

So IDE does not propagate chosen profile to the published artifacts from repo (like `my-3rd-party-deps`).

The solution was to create separate POMs (e.g. `my-3rd-party-deps-jboss` and `my-3rd-party-deps-wildfly`) and import the appropriate POM in the profile `dependencyManagement` section of every parent project.

Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

In your base pom you should have

`<modules>
     <module>subModule</module>
 </modules>`

then in your submodule pom you should have

`<parent>
        <artifactId>something</artifactId>
        <groupId>something</groupId>
        <version>something</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <--Notice the path
 </parent>`

Have you try'ed other scopes besides import?

If you use other scope then import, you should be able to use only the groupId and the artifactId in your submodule. As you had already defined the version and the scope in the base pom.
You can override them if you use some other version or scope in your submodule.

Other thing that you could do is in your base pom define a properties

`<properties>
        <project.jboss.artifact>1.5</project.jboss.artifact>
</properties>`

And in the artifact version (in your submodule pom) you could use the variable

`<version>${project.jboss.artifact}</version>`